# mariaDB syntax error (stored procedure with if statement and parameters)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

> Hello and Good day..
>   I need some help on my stored procedures query using shell or cmd.`
>   This is my bookAuthor table

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| authorID    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| authorLname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| authorFname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| authorMname | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`
```

> If i use a single operation without if statement like the query below it works fine

```
 MariaDB [library]> create procedure selectAll()
    -> select * from bookAuthor;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.60 sec)
```

> But if i use an if statement and put a parameters like the query below

```
 MariaDB [library]> create procedure insertUpdateSelectDelete
    -> (
    -> id int(11),
    -> lname varchar(50),
    -> fname varchar(50),
    -> mname varchar(50),
    -> statementtype varchar(30)
    -> )
    -> if statementtype = 'Insert'
    -> insert into bookAuthor
    -> (
    -> authorLname,
    -> authorFname,
    -> authorMname
    -> )
    -> values
    -> (
    -> lname,
    -> fname,
    -> mname
    -> )
    -> if statementtype = 'Update'
    -> update bookAuthor set
    -> authorLname = lname,
    -> authorFname = fname,
    -> authorMname = mname
    -> where authorID = id
    -> if statementtype = 'Select'
    -> select * from bookAuthor
    -> if statementtype = 'Delete'
    -> delete from bookAuthor where authorID = id;
```

> it will return an error like this

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into bookAuthor
(
authorLname,
authorFname,
authorMname
)
values
(
lname,' at line 10
```

Comment: You are missing `DELIMITER` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have numerous problems with your code. Firstly, `IF` statements require a `THEN` after the condition, and must be terminated with an `END IF`. Secondly, all statements in the procedure must be terminated with a `;`. Try this instead:

```
create procedure insertUpdateSelectDelete(
    id int(11),
    lname varchar(50),
    fname varchar(50),
    mname varchar(50),
    statementtype varchar(30)
)
begin
    if statementtype = 'Insert' then
        insert into bookAuthor (authorLname,authorFname,authorMname)
        values (lname,fname,mname);
    elseif statementtype = 'Update' then
        update bookAuthor
        set authorLname = lname, authorFname = fname, authorMname = mname
        where authorID = id;
    elseif statementtype = 'Select' then
        select * from bookAuthor;
    elseif statementtype = 'Delete' then
        delete from bookAuthor where authorID = id;
    end if;
end
```

Note that if you write the procedure as an `IF/ELSEIF` block as I have you don't strictly need the `BEGIN/END` wrapper as there is only one statement in the procedure.

Here's a [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e6f80f2f0c4cce37cab476607d6b3e98) of the procedure working.